# Producing a bar chart with height and color determined by two distinct lists

Tags: graphics, plotting

I am trying to visualize a list of positive integers using a bar chart.  In general, integers in that list may appear more than once.  For example, I may have

```
list=Sort@RandomInteger[{1,10},20]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10}
> ```

The bar chart I have in mind has the shape of

```
BarChart[DeleteDuplicates[list], BarSpacing -> 0, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[]]
```

> [image]

It basically forgets about the multiplicity of each integer.  I prefer to have the multiplicity reflected in the color of the bars, so

```
BarChart[Tally[list][[All, 2]], BarSpacing -> 0, 
    ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

> [image]

has the color scheme I want on my first bar chart.

Here is a slightly more general problem:

> Given two lists containing the same number of positive integers, to produce a bar chart with heights and colors determined by the respective lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one approach, where we compute the heights using the first part of the results from `Tally`, and the colors using the second part.  Then it's just a simple use of `ChartStyle`.

```
list = Sort@RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 20]

(*
==> {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10}
*)

{height, color} = Transpose[Tally[list]]

(*
==> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 7, 1, 2}}
*)

color = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[color];

BarChart[height, ChartStyle -> color, BarSpacing -> 0, 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, beat me by a couple of minutes, too. Also, I didn't realize that `Rescale` could operate on an entire list at once.

Comment: @rcollyer I love being able to use that feature of `Rescale`.

Comment: It certainly makes life easier than having to determine min-max first, and then `Rescale[#, {min,max}]& /@ list`. A lot less code to get wrong.

Comment: @rcollyer Even if you need to specify the min and max, you can still use `Rescale[list, {min,max}]`.

Comment: I'm aware, now. But, old habits die hard.

Comment: @Brett Thank you for the simple solution.  I was working with `ChartElementFunction`, not realizing that `ChartStyle` is the option I ought to be using.  I just could not get rid of the gaps between successive rectangles when I used `ChartElementFunction`.

Comment: it would be interesting to add a legend which shows the meaning of the colors

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using `ChartStyle` as Brett shows, you can also use `Style` directly.

Here using indexed colors:

```
list = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10};

dat = # ~Style~ ColorData[3][#2] & @@@ Tally@list;

BarChart[dat, BarSpacing -> 0, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here using a color gradient:

```
dat =
  MapThread[
    # ~Style~ ColorData["Rainbow"][#2] &, 
    MapAt[Rescale, Tally[list]\[Transpose], 2]
  ];

BarChart[dat, BarSpacing -> 0, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]